# Android - is onStart() called immediately after onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onstart

If I have two activities A and B. And I create an intent that initiates activity B from the onCreate() of activity A, when will the onStart() of activity A be called?

For example, let us say I had the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
}
```

Will the onStart() method of that activity be called as soon as these lines of code finish executing or will it create activity B first?

Comment: You can easily find out by adding some logging.

Comment: Does Activity A even get a chance to start when it's immediately pushed to background by Activity B? What if Activity B is translucent? There is a lot of cases. Build it in a way that you're independent on concrete order of events. Don't manufacture artificial problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Work Flow

**Basic Android Activity Life Cycle**

When App opened : **onCreated()** > **onStart()** > **onResume()**

When App close : **onPause()**

Here in your case below is the work flow

**Action 1:**  Activity A opened

- onCreate() of Activity A called

**Action 2**:   Activity B started

- onStart()  of Activity A called
- onResume()  of Activity A called
- onPause() of Activity A called
- onCreate() of  Activity B called
- onStart()  of  Activity B called
- onResume() of  Activity B called